# Can mixpanel.increment be used before mixpanel.people.set?

Tags: analytics, mixpanel

I am adding mixpanel to my website. I am facing a few issues here:

The following are the people properties that we are tracking:

```
mixpanel.people.set({
    ‘$first_name’: “Name”,
    ‘$last_name’: “Last_Name”,
    '$email': "email id",
    ‘Country’: “Country”,
    ‘Gender’: “Male/Female”,
    '$created': date of sign up,
    'Last Login':Date
    ‘Username’: “username”,
    ‘Login Page’: ‘Name of page from where user clicked login’,
    ‘Number of visits’:
    ‘Number of snippets plays’:
    ‘Number of mixes Created’:
    ‘Number of full songs played’:
    ‘Number of snippets created’:
    ‘Number of upvotes given’:
    ‘Number of favourites given’:
    ‘Number of Downvotes given’:
    ‘Number of snippet Shares’:
    'Number of Mix Shares':
    ‘Number of Users Invited’:
    ‘Number of mixes collected’:
    'Number of mixes played':
})
```

We are creating the user profile during sign up since that is when we will be receiving the data with email, id, name, etc. The issue is that play trbble, play full song and play mix functionality is allowed in the logged out mode as well. Hence, all this data will not be captured unless the user signs up. Is there a way we can create a profile for a logged out user and keep incrementing the values of trbble plays/mix play/full song plays and then on sign up add the other properties?

How can I increment number of plays without having to set it explicitly everytime the play event is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

**Create a profile for a user on their first visit and set only your initial known values.**

```
mixpanel.people.set({
        ‘Number of visits’:0
        ‘Number of snippets plays’:0
        ‘Number of mixes Created’:0
        ‘Number of full songs played’:0
        ‘Number of snippets created’:0
        ‘Number of upvotes given’:0
        ‘Number of favourites given’:0
        ‘Number of Downvotes given’:0
        ‘Number of snippet Shares’:0
        'Number of Mix Shares':0
        ‘Number of Users Invited’:0
        ‘Number of mixes collected’:0
        'Number of mixes played':0
    })
```

You can increment those values at anytime you want and they will be incremented on Mixpanel. The unique Mixpanel ID will be used.

**Create an alias upon signup or identify user upon login**

*Upon signup*

```
mixpanel.alias("INTERNAL_USER_ID");
```

Then set the rest of the properties like `$first_name`, `$email`, etc...

*Upon login*

```
mixpanel.identify("INTERNAL_USER_ID");
```

Mixpanel will do the rest!